# Remove part of URL with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite part of url but without result so far...

My url looks like this (the `name` segment is different for every page):

www.example.com/gallery/name/about/page.html

and after rewrite should looks like that:

www.example.com/about/page.html

I'm trying with this rewrite, but it didn't work

`RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/]+)/about/page.html$ /about/page.html? [R=301,L]`

my whole htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /gallery
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?kohana_uri=$1 [QSA,PT,L]
   RewriteRule ^$ index.php?kohana_uri=$1 [QSA,PT,L]
   RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) $1 [QSA,R,L]
   RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/]+)/about/page.html$ /about/page.html? [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>
  php_value eaccelerator.enable 0
  php_value xcache.cacher off
  php_value xcache.optimizer off
```

Comment: google find some how that link (?), and all should go to about/page.html

Comment: That rule should work. Are there more rules in your .htaccess? If yes post your complete .htaccess in your question.

Comment: @anubhava check now - I added my `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your code this way:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /gallery

   RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ $1 [R,L]
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/about/page\.html$ /about/page.html? [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?kohana_uri=$1 [QSA,PT,L]
 </IfModule>
  php_value eaccelerator.enable 0
  php_value xcache.cacher off
  php_value xcache.optimizer off
```